# Efficient functional list iteration in Python

Tags: python, haskell, functional-programming

So suppose I have an array of some elements. Each element have some number of properties.

I need to filter this list from some subsets of values determined by predicates. This subsets of course can have intersections.
I also need to determine amount of values in each such subset.

So using imperative approach I could write code like that and it would have running time of 2*n. One iteration to copy array and another one to filter it count subsets sizes.

```
from split import import groupby

a = [{'some_number': i, 'some_time': str(i) + '0:00:00'} for i in range(10)]


# imperative style

wrong_number_count = 0
wrong_time_count = 0

for item in a[:]:
    if predicate1(item):
        delete_original(item, a)
        wrong_number_count += 1

    if predicate2(item):
        delete_original(item, a)
        wrong_time_count += 1

    update_some_data(item)

do_something_with_filtered(a)


def do_something_with_filtered(a, c1, c2):
    print('filtered a {}'.format(a))
    print('{} items had wrong number'.format(c1))
    print('{} items had wrong time'.format(c2))


def predicate1(x):
    return x['some_number'] < 3


def predicate2(x):
    return x['some_time'] < '50:00:00'
```

Somehow I can't think of the way to do that in Python in functional way with same running time.
So in functional style I could have used groupby multiple times probably or write a comprehension for each predicate, but that's obviously would be slower than imperative approach.

I think such thing possible in Haskell using Stream Fusion (am I right?)
But how do that in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has a strong support to "stream processing" in the form of its iterators - and what you ask seens just trivial to do. You just have to have a way to group your predicates and attributes to it - it could be a dictionary where the predicate itself is the key.

That said, a simple iterator function that takes in your predicate data structure, along with the data to be processed could do what you want. TThe iterator would have the side effect of changing your data-structure with the predicate-information. If you want "pure functions" you'd just have to duplicate the predicate information before, and maybe passing and retrieving all predicate and counters valus to the iterator (through the `send` method) for each element - I don´ t think it would be worth that level of purism.

That said you could have your code something along:

```
from collections import OrderedDict


def predicate1(...):
    ...

...

def preticateN(...):
    ...

def do_something_with_filtered(item):
    ...

def multifilter(data, predicates):
    for item in data:
        for predicate in predicates:
            if predicate(item):
                predicates[predicate] += 1
                break
        else:
            yield item


def do_it(data):
    predicates = OrderedDict([(predicate1, 0), ..., (predicateN, 0)  ])
    for item in multifilter(data, predicates):
        do_something_with_filtered(item)

    for predicate, value in predicates.items():
        print("{} filtered out {} items".format(predicate.__name__, value)


a = ...
do_it(a)
```

(If you have to count an item for all predicates that it fails, then an obvious change from the "break" statement to a state flag variable is enough)

Comment: Hmmm..more like an S.O. + back and forth navigation buttons glitch - I intended just to edit this one to add the final comment.

Comment: do_something_with_filtered is a functions that takes a list, not an item. But I see what you did here.

Comment: I wrote the most usual pattern - each item is consumed as it is generated. Otherwise, just call `multifilter` in a generator_expression (or list comprehension if you really need a list) you will get a full list that can be passed along: 
`do_something_with_filtered_items([item for item in multifilter(data, predicates)])`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, fusion in Haskell will often turn something written as two passes into a single pass.  Though in the case of lists, it's actually foldr/build fusion rather than stream fusion.

That's not generally possible in languages that don't enforce purity, though.  When side effects are involved, it's no longer correct to fuse multiple passes into one.  What if each pass performed output?  Unfused, you get all the output from each pass separately.  Fused, you get the output from both passes interleaved.

It's possible to write a fusion-style framework in Python that will work correctly if you promise to only ever use it with pure functions. But I'm doubtful such a thing exists at the moment. (I'd loved to be proven wrong, though.)

Comment: I know that fusion would work only with pure functions, what I was asking is is there a way to do that in Python (maybe not with stream fusion, but something else) (I assume your answer is no).